# Enable trackpoint/pointstick while typing - dell e7470

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dell, trackpoint

I've got a huge problem with using trackpoint on my new `DELL Latitude e7470`. This ultrabook has a feature which prevents the use of the mouse (touchpad/trackpoint) while typing. Whenever I press a key while moving the mouse with the pointstick the mouse cursor stops moving.  It works like that in linux, windows and even uefi. So this option must be enabled in hardware. In windows it's easy to repair. Ir requires one modification in regedit. How do you disable this feature in kubuntu?

Comment: Really ? Nobody can help with this ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `xinput --list`